# Let R be the region between the curve $y = -(x-2)^2+1$ and the x-axis. Find the volume of the region obtained by revolving R about the y-axis.

Tags: definite-integrals, solid-of-revolution

The question is simple enough, but I am unable to get the correct answer even after multiple tries. I integrate the volume element $pi*x^2*dy$ between y equals [0, -3].

Comment: Why are you integrating dy? Use vertical slices and integrate dx.

Comment: Horizontal slices lets me get the area element as a circle. I am not able to imagine  the area element if i take vertical slices.

Comment: Then you must have the wrong graph.

Comment: The graph would be a inverted parabola with roots at x = (1, 3).  If the revolution is around the Y axis then wouldn't the disc element formed be perpendicular to Y axix with radius element in X

Comment: Oops -- my error -- I misread it. I though it was around the x-axis. But still, use vertical slices, with cylindrical shells, not disks.

Comment: Is the answer $8\pi/3$??

Comment: The quetstion is a MCQ, and 8pi/3 is not an available option. Could you please share your approach.

Comment: You should read in your book about the shell method.

Comment: What does MCQ stand for?

Comment: Multiple Choice Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using vertical slices, the integral is 
$$\int_{1}^3 2\pi \,r(x)h(x) dx$$
where 
$$h(x) = -(x-2)^2 + 1$$
and
$$r(x) = x$$

Comment: By the way, the integral I posted yields an answer of $\dfrac{16\pi}{3}$. Is that the book answer?

Comment: Got it. You are correct. Apologies. 16pi/3 is an available answer

Comment: One follow up. Why didn't you integrate between 0 and 1. Isn't the solid implied by the question created between y axis and the curve given by y.

Comment: Draw the parabola. Then for a typical x between 1 and 3, draw a vertical slice from the $x$-axis to the curve. The height of the slice is the height of the curve above the $x$-axis (i.e., the $y$-value for the chosen x). The width of the slice is $\Delta x$ (which becomes $dx$ in the integral). If you revolve that slice around the $y$-axis, you get what is called a "cylindrical shell". The volume of that shell is its thickness, $\Delta x$, times its surface area which we take as $2\pi\, r(x)\, h(x)$.

Comment: The radius of the shell corresponding to the vertical slice at a chosen x value (between 1 and 3) is the horizontal distance from the y-axis to the shell -- which is just x.